# IE8 right float not working and

Tags: internet-explorer-8

This div isn't floating right (its aligned with the left margin in IE8) and is cut off. Fine in IE9,10 and all other browsers. Tried searching a solution on here but no luck.

```
    <div id="main" class="wrapper">
<div id="primary" class="site-content">
<div id="content" role="main" class="homeContent">
    <article id="post-6" class="post-6 page type-page status-publish hentry">
<header class="entry-header">
<div class="entry-content">
<div id="homeinnerContent">
   <h1>Charting Client&#8217;s Financial Futures</h1>
   <div id="homeICleft">
   <p>Our mission is to help clients navigate their way through the complexities of an
ever-changing financial world.</p> 
<p>Our approach begins with listening to our clients and helping them identify their
financial goals.</p>
<p>From there, we help our clients develop a complete strategy to meet those goals
through innovative, integrated financial solutions.</p></div>
<div id="homeICright">
<div id="ctabutton1"><a href="/wealth-management/">WEALTH MANAGEMENT</a></div>
<div id="ctabutton2"><a href="/risk-management/">RISK MANAGEMENT</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
<footer class="entry-meta">         
</footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
</article><!-- #post -->            
    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
</div><!-- #main .wrapper -->

#homeinnerContent {
background: url(images/homeInnerBG.png) #000000 no-repeat;
width: 640px;
height: 270px;
float: right;
border: 2px solid white;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 15px 0 10px 15px;
color: #FFFFFF;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The float is working just fine for me in IE8.  You may want to check to see if you are in compatability mode.  If so, adding a width of 100% to the parent container(s) should fix it.  Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733350/css-quirk-in-ie8-compatibility-mode).